# Spark job works with spark-submit but fails in an oozie job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, oozie

Using Spark 2.0.0, Oozie 4.2.0. I tried to run a spark job with oozie and got this error:

```
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1473318730987_0107/container_1473318730987_0107_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 481, in __init__
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1473318730987_0107/container_1473318730987_0107_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 177, in getOrCreate
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1473318730987_0107/container_1473318730987_0107_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 211, in __init__
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

[pyspark/sqlsession.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L211) is trying to instantiate `sc._jvm.SparkSession`, but it's not a class so it fails. It worked with `spark-submit` though, so I wrote a simple script to see what was the difference, `get_session.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
print "sc._jvm.SparkSession:", sc._jvm.SparkSession
```

When run with `spark-submit`:

```
$ spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster get_session.py
...
sc._jvm.SparkSession <py4j.java_gateway.JavaClass object at  0x7f7e8194f850>
...
```

When called from an oozie workflow:

```
<workflow-app name="testing" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
  <start to="initSystem"/>

  <action name="initSystem">
    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
      <configuration> 
        <property>
          <name>oozie.launcher.yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
          <value>SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark/</value>
        </property>
        <property>  
          <name>oozie.launcher.mapred.child.env</name> 
          <value>PYSPARK_ARCHIVES_PATH=pyspark.zip</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
      <master>yarn</master>
      <mode>cluster</mode>
      <name>testing</name>
      <class></class>
      <jar>${workflowPath}/get_session.py</jar>
      <spark-opts>--py-files py4j-src.zip,pyspark.zip</spark-opts>
    </spark>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="end"/>
  </action>

  <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

The output is:

```
sc._jvm.SparkSession: <py4j.java_gateway.JavaPackage object at 0x7fc8eb1f8b50>
```

Note that `sc._jvm.SparkSession` is a `py4j.java_gateway.JavaClass` in the first case (that's ok), but it's a `py4j.java_gateway.JavaPackage` in the second; that's not ok, this is the generic object returned when that object name is not available.

Any ideas? all of this worked with Spark 1.6.0 but there was no `SparkSession` there.